# Linking to a URL with token authentication

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, ember.js

I have an a website powered by django and django-rest-framework on the server side, and ember.js on client side.  One piece of functionality that is provided is autogenerated PDF reports, which are created server-side when a certain URL is hit with a GET query.  However, the URL required authentication in the form of a token.  Currently I am trying to get the PDF report to show in a web page by using this html

```
<embed class="pdf" src="/api/pdf/report1" type='application/pdf'>
```

The link is actually populated by ember using a handlebars' `bind-attr` helper.  The problem is that this does not allow any way of passing an authentication token.  The alternative is to execute the request using an ajax query which would make it very easy to add the token, but I have no idea how to display the PDF then.

What is the best approach for this sort of problem, and any pointers as to how to solve it?

Comment: I remember having similar problem, we decided that accessing document without authentication was the easiest way. If it's not an options you can try to add token into cookie, which will be passed with request.

Comment: What do you mean about passing the token in the cookie?  AFAIK cookies aren't really involved with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use bind-attr to bind to a computed property where you can combine the URL with the token.  Not understanding the issue unless I'm oversimplifying.  I'm assuming you already have the token.

Comment: I have the token, but I'm not sure how you would combine it with the URL.  The server expects it in the request header.